# How to handle markup (HTML) in logstash

Tags: html, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am using logstash with the JDBC driver to bulk import a bunch of data from SQL Server to Elasticsearch.  (The end goal is to have this data be searchable from a web front-end.)

One of the table columns contains HTML tags (`<span id='blah'>`, `<p class='foo'>`, etc).  I want the content to be searchable, but the tags to be ignored.  That is if someone searches for the word "foo", the document that contains `<p class='foo'>` should NOT come up. On the other hand, I DO want the full content, including markup, to stored in Elasticsearch.

Is there something I can do in my logstash `.config` file to make Elasticsearch "aware" that this is HTML content?

Comment: Perhaps the question can be summarized as "make field unsearchable"?
 With the field to make unsearchable is the field containing the tag.

Comment: To make a field unsearchable, I think it is possible to use the `index : false` option of a mapping, on the field with the tags.

Comment: @baudsp - To clarify, I want the tags to be ignored, but the "real" content SHOULD be searchable.  I will edit my question.

Comment: i've never done it before, but I think what you are looking for is the `html_strip` filter/analyzer.  It would be applied on the ES side, not logstash.

Comment: From what I understood, all the tags (`<p class='foo'>`) are in just one column, with the real content in another column. With the jdbc plugin, each column from the table is a field in a document, so that's why I said to make that field not indexed.